# Can firebase android SDK work without sockets?

Tags: android, sockets, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

We've deployed a real-time solution (on top of firebase) which communicates over a 3g network.
For commercial purposes, we are looking into agreements with a network provider which would provide some sort of a firewall, which whitelists only a specific set of domain names or IPs provided by us. Unfortunately, they've mentioned that socket communication will not be supported in this.

I know that the javascript firebase SDK falls back to http in case sockets are not available. Is there a fallback available in the android SDK as well, which would allow firebase to function even in the absence of socket IO?

(I know that the REST APIs allow this, just wanted to know if the firebase SDK would automatically fall-back to this, or do I have to do this manually)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firebase JavaScript SDK will indeed access the database using long polling in browsers where Web Sockets are not available.

The native Firebase SDKs for Android and iOS do not have such fallback, since these mobile platforms support sockets natively.